# Swipe para a direita depois de esquerda dá erro ANDROID

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2, debug, apk

Estou a criar uma aplicação em Android em Eclipse com 3 screen com Swipe horizontal, na última aba tenho um Map Fragment.

Mas acontece que ao fazer swipe para a direita a primeira vez está tudo normal, ao fazer um swipe para a esquerda e voltar a fazer um para a direita a aplicação crasha e aparece-me este erro, o que poderá ser?

Obrigado desde já

```
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353): Process: com.sapires.JoesPizzariaGEN, PID: 10353
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.sapires.JoesPizzaria.Mapa.onCreateView(Mapa.java:16)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f070016, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5002)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
07-29 23:35:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(10353):    ... 25 more
```

Layout do `Fragment` `Map`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Classe

```
    package com.sapires.JoesPizzaria;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new APizzaria();
        case 1:
            return new Ementa();
        case 2:
            return new Mapa();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3; //No of Tabs
    }
    }
```

Comment: Coloque o layout do `Fragment` `Mapa`. Como está sendo feita a remoção e inserção dos fragmentos? Tem certeza que não está deixando dois fragmentos iguais na `Activity`?

Comment: Inclua esses códigos editando sua pergunta, fica mais legível.

Comment: Ok, adicionei á pergunta, obrigado

Comment: Recomendo fazer o seguinte, tire o `id` do `<fragment>` e use tag. Para recuperar o `fragment`, use o `findFragmentByTag` do `FragmentManager`.

Comment: pode exemplificar pf, o que é tag? Obrigado

Comment: Já tive esse problemas antes, e como tag é uma forma de identificar unicamente uma instância de fragmento assim como o id, tenho minhas dúvidas se vai resolver. O caso é que o aplicativo está tentando adicionar ao FragmentManager duas instâncias de MapFragment identificadas da mesma forma, o que não é permitido. Seria o caso de aumentar o offscreenPageLimit ou remover o MapFragment do FragmentManager antes de adicionar outra instância dele.

Comment: Então como posso resolver?

Comment: Vou explicar em uma resposta, peraí.

Comment: este é o projeto: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xozvj40uezkmg7/SwipeTab.rar

Answer (score 1):

O erro é devido ao `LayoutInflater` tentar adicionar ao layout da Activity um fragmento que já havia sido adicionado anteriormente (exceção disparada [aqui](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java#4791)). O motivo disso é que o `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` está querendo exibir o mesmo fragmento duas vezes na tela. Ele faz isso porque não está removendo o fragmento do `FragmentManager` quando deveria, pois trata-se de um fragmento "filho" do fragmento que é efetivamente removido (fragmento dentro de outro fragmento ou *nested fragment*). O fragmento "pai" é removido do `FragmentManager` e o "filho" fica. O fragmento-filho em questão é o `MapFragment` incluído em `res/layout/mapa.xml` com id `R.id.fragment`.

O erro **não** é devido ao aplicativo tentar adicionar ao `FragmentManager` duas instâncias de `MapFragment` identificadas da mesma forma, como eu havia afirmado anteriormente.

### Solução

De acordo com [esta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14293779/2241463) para os *nested fragments* funcionarem o fragmento-filho tem que ser adicionado dinamicamente no código ao invés de inclui-lo no layout como está sendo feito. [Este  trecho da documentação](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) ilustra isso:

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a <fragment>. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

Isso significa que o código dos arquivos `/res/layout/mapa.xml` e `Mapa.java` devem ser alterados da seguinte maneira (note a substituição de `MapFragment` por `SupportMapFragment`, entre outras alterações):

**`/res/layout/mapa.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

**`Mapa.java`**

```
package com.sapires.JoesPizzaria;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.sapires.JoesPizzariaGEN.R;

public class Mapa extends Fragment {

    private SupportMapFragment mFragmentoDoMapa;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View windows = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa, container, false);
        return windows;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mFragmentoDoMapa = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.container, mFragmentoDoMapa);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentoDoMapa).commit();
    }
}
```

Note porém que isso acrescenta *flicker* quando o usuário vai para a aba do mapa, isto é, a tela dá uma "piscada" devido à adição repentina do `SupportMapFragment` ao layout. Para resolver isso, faça o `ViewPager` instanciar somente uma vez os fragmentos criados para cada aba e preservar essas instâncias entre as mudanças de tela acrescentando a linha `Tab.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` à classe `MainActivity.java`:

```
Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
Tab.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

### Outra possível solução

Voce pode remover a instância do `MapFragment` do `FragmentManager` junto com a destruição do fragmento `Mapa`. Um lugar em que isso pode ser feito é imediatamente antes da linha `return new Mapa();`, faça da forma como você está fazendo em `Mapa` para remover o fragmento com o id `R.id.fragment`. Outro local em que isso pode ser feito é em um dos métodos `Mapa.onDestroyView()`, `Mapa.onDetach()` ou `Mapa.onDestroy()` (este último é o mais apropriado).

Comment: Desculpe mas não consegui compreender, ja alterei o Mapa.onDestroyView() por Mapa.onDetach() e continua igual, o resto da explicação é muito complicada para mim...

Comment: @Piovezan, é muito estranho isso... Olhando o código fonte do `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java). Ele deveria tirar o `Fragment` antes de adicionar outro. Nos layouts do projeto dele não tem nenhum `id` repetido não?

Comment: @SaPires O que você não entendeu? O método `Tab.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` pode ser chamado em `MainActivity`, por exemplo abaixo da linha  `Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);`. Como alternativa ao `Tab.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)` você pode mover o código de `Mapa.onDestroyView()` para `MainActivity`, colocando-o imediatamente acima da linha `return new Mapa();`. Outra coisa (uma terceira alternativa), sobre a orientação de mover o código para `onDetach()`, por desencargo tente mover para `Mapa.onDestroy()`, talvez funcione.

Comment: @Wakim Não há `id` repetido não, o caso é que o adapter até remove o fragmento "pai", mas há um fragmento "filho" (fragmento dentro de outro fragmento) que ele não remove, que é o `MapFragment` declarado em `map.xml`. Esse fragmento "filho" é criado e adicionado ao `FragmentManager` implicitamente quando o fragmento-pai `Mapa` é criado na linha `return new Mapa();`, e não é removido em nenhum momento.

Comment: Eu recomendaria tirar os `ids` e usar as `tag`, talvez o `FragmentManager` esteja se perdendo em relação a remoção dos `Fragments`. E recomendo não chamar os métodos `onDetach` e `onDestroyView` manualmente. Esses métodos são chamados conforme o ciclo de vida do `Fragment`.

Comment: Esses métodos não estão sendo chamados manualmente. É que dentro deles há código que remove o fragmento de id `R.id.fragment` (o tal fragmento "filho"), é a esse código que me refiro.

Comment: @Wakim Em qual parte do código o @SaPires vai poder usar tags? Quem adiciona os fragmentos ao `FragmentManager` é o `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` de forma implícita e usando id, não o código do aplicativo.

Comment: Percebi a ideia mas fico sempre com erros :( é possivel editar o projeto de https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xozvj40uezkmg7/SwipeTab.rar MUITO OBRIGADO

Comment: @SaPires Desculpe, mas o objetivo do site não é jogar o código na mão dos outros e esperar que resolvam o problema por você. Tem que haver esforço da sua parte também. Se você está encontrando problemas, acrescente-os à sua questão ou nos comentários e participe da resolução dos mesmos. Se uma explicação não estiver clara o suficiente, pergunte.

Comment: Tem razão, finalmente consegui, criei este metodo: @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
     super.onDestroyView();
     Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
     if (f != null) 
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
 }

Comment: Isso resolveu o problema? Outra coisa, aproveitei e corrigi a explicação do problema em minha resposta, que estava incorreta.

Comment: Sim resolveu o meu problema, ou seja é preciso "limpar" o mapa antes de carregar novamente com o swipe

Comment: @SaPires, como essa resposta resolveu seu problema, recomendo que marque a resposta como correta, assim outros irão se orientar melhor e evitar que outras pessoas achem que o problema não foi resolvido.

Comment: @SaPires Detalhei uma solução melhor na minha resposta, recomendo usá-la. Se estiver ok para você, aceite a resposta conforme explicado [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).